# MFC tabbed MDI : too many OnAfterTaskbarActivate()

Tags: mfc

(My English can be strange o_o)

I work with MFC tabbed MDI, No Document/View

I delete auto-generated View Class, and use `CSplitterWnd` and my own View Class

"my own View Class" has two child: edit control and my custom control

(edit: I created new tabbed MDI, No Document/View MFC Project and tested that project by spy++. and the following problem occur AGAIN!)
(edit: Use Document/View: AGAIN!)

While I write this program, I found a strange problem:

When I validate window by clicking Aero Peek Thumbnail, my custom control is drawn so many times (WM_PAINT is sent many times)

I figured out `CMDIFrameWndEx::OnAfterTaskbarActivate` function calls `RedrawWindow` in that WM_PAINT, and OnAfterTaskbarActivate is callen so many times (31 times, yah)

Could you tell me what makes this problem and how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as this. My Solution is to override the OnAfterTaskbarActivate

add this to your MessageMap

```
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(AFX_WM_AFTER_TASKBAR_ACTIVATE, OnAfterTaskbarActivate)
```

the function is as follows. please note this is exactly the same as the original function without the redraw.

```
LRESULT CMainFrame::OnAfterTaskbarActivate(WPARAM, LPARAM lp)
    {
    HWND hwndMDIChild = (HWND)lp;
    if (hwndMDIChild != NULL && ::IsWindow(hwndMDIChild))
        {
        ::SetFocus(hwndMDIChild);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

I hope this helps. it has resolved my issues.

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much for your answer! I've thought my answer is ignored(?) ;; I'll give it a try and accept answer, thanks!

Comment: It works perfectly! Btw, Why does it happen? I remember it doesn't happen at previous version of MFC(or Visual Studio?).